# Python ASTEVAL. How can i capture stdout

Tags: python, exec, eval, stdout

I consider using [`asteval` python package](https://github.com/newville/asteval) for my personal web app.

> ASTEVAL is a safe(ish) evaluator of Python expressions and statements, using Python's ast module. The idea is to provide a simple, safe, and robust miniature mathematical language that can handle user-input.

The issue I faced is that I couldn't obtain stdout of asteval. I tried to capture it using the following snippet:

```
from asteval import Interpreter

aeval = Interpreter()

from cStringIO import StringIO
import sys

class Capturing(list):
    def __enter__(self):
        self._stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self._stringio = StringIO()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.extend(self._stringio.getvalue().splitlines())
        sys.stdout = self._stdout
```

and then:

```
with Capturing() as output:
    aeval('print "this should be captured"')
```

but no luck, `output` is an empty list.

Comment: I really really warn you not to use this library, Its horribly and easily broken.

Comment: how can it be broken? what are the alternatives?

Comment: [pypy-sandbox](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sandbox.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a file object (`writer`) to the `Interpreter()` class:

```
output = StringIO()
aeval = Interpreter(writer=output)
```

`writer` defaults to `sys.stdout` if you don't specify it, and set when `Interpreter()` is instantiated. This is why replacing `sys.stdout` doesn't work; the instance already has their own reference to it.

Demo:

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> from asteval import Interpreter
>>> output = StringIO()
>>> aeval = Interpreter(writer=output)
>>> aeval('print "this should be captured"')
>>> output.getvalue()
'this should be captured\n'
```

Comment: So quick! Thanks, it works for me great! Will be able to accept answer in 3 mins